# How can i buy DLCs via Nintendo Eshop on my Computer?

Tags: nintendo-eshop

How can I buy DLCs via Nintendo eShop on my Computer? When I enter in the eShop, I only see the games but not the DLCs, or is something wrong with my Internet browser?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Nintendo eshop can only be accessed for purchases on your Wii/WiiU, or 3DS.

You cannot purchase games from it via the computer.

Comment: But what about this site?
https://checkout.nintendo.com/#/item/CTRNAXCE?lytic_locale=en-US

Comment: That allows you to buy a digital download code for the game specifically, which you would then have to enter on your Wii/WiiU/3DS as appropriate, but at this time, it does not appear to have DLC, just full releases. If you want DLC, currently your only option is to connect to the eshop through your device.